# Initialize and assign values to list of ints without a loop

Tags: c#, f#

is there a shorter way to do this:

```
        List<int> mins = new List<int>();
        for(int i = 0; i<60; i++)
        {
            mins.Add(i+1);
        }
```

Functional version also appreciated if available in c#, also f# version appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

F#:

```
open System.Collections.Generic 
let r = new List<_>( [1..60] )
```

C#:

```
var r = new List<int>(Enumerable.Range(1, 60));
```

Comment: why not `let r = new List<_>(seq {1..60})`?

Comment: That's fine too.  Or Enumerable.Range, as in the C#.  Or a bunch of other stuff.  Question asked for 'shorter', so I was going for short.

Answer (score 4):

In F#, I would probably write:

```
[ 1 .. 60 ] |> ResizeArray.ofSeq
```

This is the same as calling the constructor explicitly, but it has a little nicer syntax (you can use pipelining and you don't need to specify type parameter of the constructor).

Answer (score 3):

This would do it for the C# version:

```
List<int> mins = Enumerable.Range(1, 60).ToList();
```

That *will* loop internally, admittedly. If you are happy with an `IEnumerable<int>` instead, just knock off the `ToList` call and you'll get lazy evaluation. You've already got F# versions now, I see :)

Answer (score 2):

`List<_>` in C# is a dynamic array, not linked list. In F#, `List<_>` is `ResizeArray<_>`.

Here's the directly translated F# version:

```
let mins = new ResizeArray<int> ()
for i=0 to 60-1 do
    mins.Add(i+1)
```

You can use `ResizeArray` module:

```
#r "FSharp.PowerPack.dll"
let mins = ResizeArray.init 60 (fun i -> i+1)
```

Notice that the ResizeArray<_> type is defined in F# Core, the same name module is in F# PowerPack.